# verify if server certificate matches with root CA certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a SSL server certificate for a server and I have a root CA certificate that the client can verify this server certificate during SSL handshake. For some reason I am not sure if I really retrieved the right root certificate. Is there any way where I can see if I have the right root certificate? Maybe an openssl command in which I provide both files and the output tells me "root CA certificate confirms SSL certificate".

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The command is `openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt server.crt`
If the two certificates match, the command will return `server.crt: OK`

The above command is only for pem format.
If you has .p12 file, then first convert it to pem format:
`openssl pkcs12 -in server.p12 -out server.crt -nodes`

Comment: openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt server.p12 I have, so it is a p12 file I have. the command returns unable to load certificate.

Answer (score 0):

There is an OpenSSL function `X509_verify` using this you can verify a certificate using public key of the root.

Its sample usage I am showing below:

```
//Get the public key of the root.
EVP_PKEY * pubkey = X509_get_pubkey(ca_cert);

//Verify the certificate.
ret = X509_verify(cert, pubkey);

if(ret != 1)
   //not verified.
```

OpenSSL does not tell whether this right root certificate. You have to explicitly set it as trusted or not trusted. A root certificate is self signed and so its public key should verify it.